# Barcode Label printing-web garden-best practices –architecture design

Tags: asp.net, architecture, barcode, barcode-printing, jquery-barcode

Here is the question.
We have an (asp.net web) application that prints barcode labels. I have basically two approaches. The environment is load balancer environment (completely secure and completely internal environment -Web garden). Let’s say we have around 200 label printers and those have to print around 100k labels every day. I am trying to design a good architecture for label printing and I am looking for suggestion on the good and best approach.
Approach1: (Server side)
Share all the printers(network sharing and installing the printers at all the servers- network-connect) and after that when user clicks on print bar code, we will track the client IP from where user has requested, and we have a mapping in database, and we will send the print response to the corresponding printer mapped through server-network shared printer.
 For this approach one time configuration is enough.

Approach2:  (Client Side)
We will do the IP-Printer configuration in database. But we won’t be sharing the printer. When user clicks on "print bar code", we will generate the label in PDF for any other font and it will be printed directly at client end based on the IP-Printer configuration through Javascript. This approach is something like everything we are planning at client end. 
Our architects have suggested that Approach1 is good. But I am saying that the load will be more on the servers instead of network sharing those printers. I've suggested to them to leave it at the client end. And in the approach 2 we won’t ask the client on which printer the label should be printed because we will do a database look up on the IP-Printer configuration, and my client-side program will directly print the labels on the printers that are connect to the client machine.

Comment: while posting this question I got a warning that this is subjective question. But this is architecture question and I hope it is valid here.

Comment: Well we figured out the solution: We create a Self hosted WCF service and installed the same to all the client machines. When the request comes through browser to the IIS Server from there it will call the self hosted WCF service and that service prints the barcodes associated to the client machine. This approach is working fine in our environment and did not find any issues.